# Fortran Compile Error: Unclassifiable statement

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran95

Can someone please help me with the following? I am new to Fortran and am trying to run the following using a GCC for Windows.

```
program jacobi
implicit none
double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: u, u_n
double precision :: Res_2, Res_inf
integer :: i,j,mesh,unit
mesh=64

Res_2=0
allocate(u(0:mesh,0:mesh))
allocate(u_n(0:mesh,0:mesh))
u=0
u_n=0
u(:,0)=1
u_n(:,0)=1
unit=12

open(unit, file="array.txt", access='append', status='old')

do while (Res_2>1D-10)
    Res_2=0
    do (i=1,mesh-1)
        do (j=1,mesh-1)
            u(i,j)=0.25D0*(u_n(i+1,j)+u_n(i-1,j)+u_n(i,j-1))
        end do
    end do
    Res_inf=-4D0*maxval((u-u_n))
    do (i=1,mesh-1)
        do (j=1,mesh-1)
            Res_2=Res_2+(-4D0*(u(i,j)-u_n(i,j)))**2
        end do
    end do
    Res_2=sqrt(Res_2)
    write(1,*) Res_2
end do
close(unit)

end program jacobi
```

I keep getting these error while compiling:

```
jacobi.f95:21.2:

  do (i=1,mesh-1)
  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
jacobi.f95:22.3:

   do (j=1,mesh-1)
   1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
jacobi.f95:25.5:

  end do
     1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
jacobi.f95:27.2:
```

Am I using the do loop wrong? Have I declared the variable 'i,j' incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses in your statements such as

```
do (i=1,mesh-1)
```

are not acceptable, the correct form in Fortran is

```
do i=1,mesh-1
```

Having failed to see a (valid) `do` statement the compiler later complains at finding an unmatched `end do` statement.  Fix the `do` statements, the error about expecting an `end program` statement should go away.